# Can I higlight brackets / parenthesis pairings by clicking on them in Textmate?

Tags: mac, textmate

I recently started using Textmate, and I am loving it. I come from Notepad ++, and there is only one thing I miss: the ability to click on a bracket or parenthesis and highlighting the opening and closing pair.

I know you can see the pairings of a bracket or parenthesis with a keyboard shortcut (command + option + B, I think), but clicking on them is much more faster and convenient. Given that the software has this feature, I thought there must be a setting for enabling click highlighting, but I cant seem to find it.

Does anyone know if there is a way to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to do what you want in TextMate. The shortcut in your question selects the brackets/parenthesis and their content. Note that it's not "highlighting", it's "selecting".

However, when your caret passes a closing bracket TextMate flashes the opening bracket. Maybe it will be enough for you.